# PHP - Query on page with many requests

Tags: php, sql, join, pdo

I have around 700 - 800 visitors at all time on my home page (according to analytics) and a lot of hits in general. However, I wish to show live statistics of my users and other stuff on my homepage. I therefore have this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT 
    count(*) as totalusers, 
    sum(cashedout) cashedout,
    (SELECT sum(value) FROM xeon_stats_clicks 
     WHERE typ='1') AS totalclicks
    FROM users
    ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stats=$stmt->fetch();
```

Which I then use as `$stats["totalusers"]` etc.

```
table.users have `22210` rows, with index on `id, username, cashedout`, `table.xeon_stats_clicks` have index on `value` and `typ`
```

However, whenever I enable above query my website instantly becomes very slow. As soon as I disable it, the load time drastically falls.

How else can this be done?

Comment: Do you have a primary key for both the tables ?

Comment: Yes, on "Id" on both tables.

Comment: Have you looked at the `EXPLAIN` of the query to see where the chokepoint may be.

Comment: Do you need that information Live .. with caching (for some min period) it will be ok . Indexes on field typ from the inner select can be helpful too

Comment: Is `totalusers` the count of people who've registered, or people who're visiting.

Comment: You need an index on `xeon_stats_clicks.typ` because that's what the `WHERE` clause on the inner `SELECT` is filtering on.

Comment: @Svetlio caching would be Ok. Akshay: its the count for users who have registered.

Comment: @AndyLester there is an index on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** do it that way. You will eventually exhuast your precious DB resources, as you now are experiencing. The good way is to run a separate [cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php) in 30 secs or 1 min interval, and then write the result down to a file :

```php
file_put_contents('stats.txt', $stats["totalusers"]);
```

and then on your mainpage

```html
<span>current users :
   <b><? echo file_get_contents('stats.txt');?></b>
</span>
```

The beauty is, that the HTTP server will cache this file, so until `stats.txt` is changed, a copy will be upfront in cache too.

---

Example, save / load JSON by file :

```
$test = array('test' => 'qwerty');
file_put_contents('test.txt', json_encode($test));
echo json_decode(file_get_contents('test.txt'))->test;
```

will output `qwerty`. Replace `$test` with `$stats`, as in comment

```
echo json_decode(file_get_contents('stats.txt'))->totalclicks;
```

Comment: That's ... So simple. So obvious. Thank you for kicking my common sense!

Comment: Just a side question: can I write "totalcashedout" and "totalclicks" to the same file and still echo it? Or should it be 3 separate files?

Comment: @oliverbj, you could save it as JSON with `json_encode($stats)` and then parse the content after you load the file, something like `echo json_decode(file_get_contents('stats.txt'))->totalclicks;`

Comment: as JSON? This is still very new to me. Could I get you to post a simple example?

Comment: @oliverbj, you are welcome! Thank you for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, there is nothing about this query that is specific to any user on the site. So if you have this query being executed for every user that makes a request, you are making thousands of identical queries.

You could do a sort of caching like so:

Create a table that basically looks like the output of this query.

Make a PHP script that just executes this query and updates the aforementioned table with the lastest result.

Execute this PHP script as a cron job every minute to update the stats.

Then the query that gets run for every request can be real simple, like:

```
SELECT totalusers cashedout, totalclicks FROM stats_table
```

Answer (score 0):

From the query, I can't see any real reason to use a sub-query in there as it doesn't use any of the data in the users table, and it's likely that that is slowing it down - if memory serves me right it will query that xeon_clicks table once for every row in your users table (which is a lot of rows by the looks of things).

Try doing it as two separate queries rather than one.